# How should I react to strange HR behaviour?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, human-resources

I've uploaded my CV to job web site. I feel qualified for this jobs, because few months ago I've successfully finished project of the same type.

HR woman has replied asking for lower estimate of salary which I'll accept to work for. I've answered with my average number. Then she replied that company is not interested in talking with me and asked if I want to be subscribed to newsletter with job opportunities.

I feel uncomfortable after such treatment and I can't wait to reply something rude to her. Or may be I should post details of my conversation to the website where she posted this job? Is she behaving ethical? Maybe something is wrong with me?

Comment: Was this person from the job site, or a customer of theirs (another company)?  Sounds like a recruiter poaching.

Comment: Initially it looked like an insite HR, but later it looked more like a proxy HR. But i don't understand what you mean by poaching. It would be cool to see your comment as an answer.

Comment: Which part of what she said or did makes you uncomfortable and think might be unethical? Do you expect them to be willing to pay whatever you ask for? Or to continue the interview process even when they're not willing to pay the salary you want?

Comment: It's not clear which part you took offense to. Are you angry about how the salary conversation, the newsletter thing, or something else?

Comment: I have invested my time in finetuning resume, posting it, conversating, thinking about changing job, etc. So essentially her behavior shows disrespect for my time/energy.

Comment: Assuming the company is not willing to pay what you ask for, what behavior would you have *expected* from her?

Comment: Never waste you time on companies that undermine you.

Comment: @StepanYakovenko  The time you spend is part of the expense of job hunting.  They're not asking to be paid for the time they spent evaluating you as a candidate.  See [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6978/is-it-my-right-to-know-the-test-results/7004#7004).

Comment: This seems to be a clear case of mismatch between budget and expectations. That's perfectly normal and it's actually good if you identify it early in the process. It's hard to see what you are upset about? Would you have preferred to continue the process only to get offers that are substantially below what you want/need ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What do you hope to accomplish by either emailing something rude to her or posting something bad on a web site?

Granted you might have blown off some steam.

But is it not better to take it in the chin and maintain your reputation. The world is an increasing small place.

Comment: yeah, absolutely almost nothing constructive really

Comment: if you need to blow off steam: write the letter (on paper), and then throw it away.

Answer (score 12):

> HR woman has replied asking for lower estimate of salary which I'll accept to work for. I've answered with my average number. Then she replied that company is not interested in talking with me and asked if I want to be subscribed to newsletter with job opportunities.

You stated a number you'd be happy to accept - clearly it was more than they were willing/able to pay and then they asked if you wanted to be kept in the loop for future opportunities. Negotiations don't always work out. All seems perfectly normal and reasonable to me.

> I feel uncomfortable after such treatment and I can't wait to reply something rude to her.

Yeah.. don't do that. If your first instinct after having a interaction that didn't go exactly to your wishes is to be rude to the other party then I think your instincts are a bit off.

> Or may be I should post details of my conversation to the website where she posted this job?

To what end? Company and candidate didn't agree on a figure - news at eleven! Coming up after the break: Pope - Catholic! Bears defecate in woods! Trying to make something out of a complete non-issue and trying to make them look bad as a result is only going to make *you* look bad.

> Is she behaving ethical?

Yes.

> Maybe something is wrong with me?

No comment.

Answer (score 1):

Don't waste your time on this company.  Unless you're asking for well above average if they don't think a fair compensation is worth the work they will receive then it isn't a company you would want to work for anyway.  It is their loss not yours.

Answer (score -1):

If the first thing the company asks for is to reduce your salary, then your only sane reply is to send your CV with changed salary requirements - increased, obviously. Not ridiculously increased, but enough to show them that you will not be taken advantage of. It's up to them to decide whether you are worth it or not, or if they think their company can survive hiring cheap and incompetent.

Being rude, on the other hand, doesn't help.

Comment: What would that accomplish ?  In this case there is clearly a mismatch between the budget and the candidate's expectation. Happens all the time. Then it's not a fit so both parties should simply move on. No harm, no foul.